# How often does SPI Master run on PSoC 5 LP?

Tags: microcontroller, spi, psoc

For a school project, I'm working with the PSoC 5 LP (CY8C5888LTI-LP097 devkit 'stick') and I am using SPI DAC's/ADC's with it (the MCP 4901 and 3001 respectively). I am having trouble understanding how to use the SPI interface. I've used the chips with Arduino SPI library in the past, and for that you initiate the transfer with a function in the library, and that's the only time the SCK line runs. However, there's not a similar function in PSoC 5. The SPI Master macro has an API function for reading from the FIFO buffer, but there's nothing that I can find in the documentation about how often the SCK line runs. This is important because the SCK line is what runs the SAR in the MCP3001, and otherwise I'm unsure of how to handle the data.

How do I control the run state of the SPI interface? Am I missing something? Should I write my own software SPI interface that is similar to the arduino SPI library's interface?